# Get Max number from array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numbers, max

I need to take the id from each element and isolate the number. After that, create an array of numbers and get the largest number. In Math.max() I get NaN. Is this a good or bad approach and why am I not getting the highest number?

```
<div class="element" id="element-2" ><div>
<div class="element" id="element-58" ><div>
<div class="element" id="element-135" ><div>
<div class="element" id="element-39" ><div>
<div class="element" id="element-78" ><div>
```

```
    var element_numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
    var max_comm = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < element_numbers.length; i++) {
        var num = element_numbers[i].id;
        const num_arr = num.match(/[0-9]+$/);
        max_comm += num_arr+",";
    }   
        var max_num = "["+max_comm.slice (0, -1)+"]";
       alert(max_num);
       alert(Math.max(max_num));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `id`s to an array and use the `sort()` function to sort the array elements and the first element of the returned array is the max value. So the code will look like:

```js
 var element_numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
var max_comm = [];
for (var i = 0; i < element_numbers.length; i++) {
    var num = element_numbers[i].id;
    const num_arr = num.match(/[0-9]+$/);
    max_comm.push(parseInt(num_arr));
}   

console.log(max_comm.sort((a, b) =>( b - a)));
alert(Math.max(...max_comm));
```

```html
<div class="element" id="element-2">
</div>
<div class="element" id="element-58">
</div>
<div class="element" id="element-135">
</div>
<div class="element" id="element-39">
</div>
<div class="element" id="element-78">
</div>
```

Comment: You must have tested the answer before I edit it. Please try the current answer, it should work correctly

Comment: I tested before you edited, now it works.

Comment: Is this the only and most correct approach? Could you please explain why?

Comment: What else do you need? It's a correct answer, and your HTML code was wrong, without closing `div` tags, `</div>`

Comment: Everything is fine, I put your answer as correct..., the only thing I'm asking is if this is the only approach, why it didn't work with math.max?

Comment: You can use it , of course, like `Math.max(...idArray)` I have updated the answer as you like

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: And you forgot to parse the string values into numbers, using `parseInt()` function